# How to search and print discord chat history with discord.py?

Tags: python, discord.py

So, I have a code that on receiving a message it will print it to the python terminal, but I want to be able to see previous messages as this code will only show messages sent while the code is running. I was thinking of getting the history printed in the startup section (`async def on_ready():`) but wasn't sure how. Thanks for your help.

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  print(f"{message.guild.name}: {message.channel.name}\n{message.author.name}: {message.content}")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've put together a way for you to query the last `x` messages in a channel of your choice with one command. For an event you have to change this accordingly or look at example two of me.

**Example 1:**

```py
@client.command() / @bot.command() / @commands.command()
async def history(ctx):
    messages = await ctx.channel.history(limit=YourLimit).flatten() # Get the history of the channel where the command was invoked
    for message in messages: # Get only the messages and not any extra information
        print(message.content, sep="\n") # Print the messages and show each in a new line
```

If you want to use this in an `on_ready` event you have to rewrite the command a bit, it could look like

**Example 2:**

```py
@client.event / @bot.event / @commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_ready():
    channel = client.get_channel(ChannelID) # A channel ID must be entered here
    messages = await channel.history(limit=YourLimit).flatten()
    for message in messages:
        print(message.content, sep="\n")
```